# Need to convert list of data into list of list based on parent child relationship

Tags: java

I need to convert list of data into list of list based on parent child relationship. If parent is null fall on to level one, level two will be based level one id.

My Data looks like below:

```
[
    {id:1, parent: null },
    {id:2, parent: 1 },
    {id:3, parent: 1 },
    {id:4, parent: 1 },
    {id:5, parent: 2 },
    {id:6, parent: 2 },
    {id:7, parent: 3 },
    {id:8, parent: 3 },
    {id:9, parent: 4 },
    {id:10, parent: 4 },
    {id:11, parent: 5 },
    {id:12, parent: null },
    {id:13, parent: 12 },
]
```

My code is:

ResponseData

```
Map<String,Map<String,ResponseData>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (ResponseData responseData : responseDataList) {
    Map<String,responseData> responseDatasMap =  map.get(responseData.getParent());
    if(responseDatasMap != null) {
        responseDatasMap.put(responseData.getId(),responseData);
        map.put(responseData.getParent(),responseDatasMap);
    } else {
        responseDatasMap =  new HashMap<>();
        responseDatasMap.put(responseData.getParent(),responseData);
        map.put(responseData.getParent(),responseDatasMap);
    }
}
```

Above map will contain parent as key and map of values mapped to parent

```
List<List<ResponseData>> sections = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,Map<String, ResponseData>> responseDataMap : map.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, ResponseData> valueMap = responseDataMap.getValue();
    responseDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, ResponseData> responseData :valueMap.entrySet()) {
        responseDataList.add(responseData.getValue());
    }
    sections.add(responseDataList);
}
```

My output looks like below :

```
[
    [ {id:1, parent: null } ],
    [ {id:2, parent: 1 },{id:3, parent: 1 },{id:4, parent: 1 } ],
    [ {id:5, parent: 2 },{id:6, parent: 2 } ],
    [ {id:7, parent: 3 },{id:8, parent: 3 } ],
    [ {id:9, parent: 4 },{id:10, parent: 4 } ],
    [ {id:11, parent: 5 }]
]
```

but My expected output required like below:

```
First level array contains the data where parent is null

Second level contains the children of level 1 ie id 2,3,4 are a child of id 1

Third level contains the children of levlel2 objects ie 5 & 6 are a child of 2 , 7 & 8 are a child of 3 and 9 & 10 child of 4

Level four contains the children of level 3 objects ie 11 is a child of id 5

[
    [ {id:1, parent: null }, {id:12, parent:null} ],
    [ {id:2, parent: 1 },{id:3, parent: 1 },{id:4, parent: 1 },{id:13, parent: 12 } ],
    [ {id:5, parent: 2 },{id:6, parent: 2 },{id:7, parent: 3 },{id:8, parent: 3 },{id:9, parent: 4 },{id:10, parent: 4 } ],
    [ {id:11, parent: 5 }]
]
```

Please check and let me know how we can implement the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you convert this to stream and keep it simple by using 'Collectors.groupingBy(parent#getId,Collection#List)` will provide good readability along with clean json representing **Key, Pair** values in UI (just a suggestion)

Comment: Yeah. I will convert the code to stream once my logic got fixed and started working as my expectation. Thanks for the suggestion @emotionlessbananas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For representing the tree structure, I have used an `ArrayList`, where the index of the node is equal to its index in the array + 1. If you have a sparse tree/some indices might be missing, use an equivalent approach with a map instead.

Solution using Java 8 stream API:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
        List<ResponseData> responseDataList = Arrays.asList(
            new ResponseData( 1, -1 ),  // changed null to -1 as null can't be a map key
            new ResponseData( 2, 1 ),
            new ResponseData( 3, 1 ),
            new ResponseData( 4, 1 ),
            new ResponseData( 5, 2 ),
            new ResponseData( 6, 2 ),
            new ResponseData( 7, 3 ),
            new ResponseData( 8, 3 ),
            new ResponseData( 9, 4 ),
            new ResponseData( 10, 4 ),
            new ResponseData( 11, 5 ),
            new ResponseData( 12, -1 ),
            new ResponseData( 13, 12 )
        );
        final Map<Integer, List<ResponseData>> map = responseDataList.stream()
                .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( o -> getLevel( responseDataList, o, 0 ) ) );
        System.out.println( map );
        // To convert the Map to a List of Lists:
        System.out.println( new ArrayList<>( map.values() ));
    }

    private static int getLevel(List<ResponseData> nodes, ResponseData responseData, int level) {
        if( responseData.parent == -1 ) {
            return level;
        } else {
            return getLevel( nodes, nodes.get( responseData.parent - 1 ), level + 1 );  // -1 to adjust index
        }
    }

    private static final class ResponseData {
        public int id;
        public int parent;

        public ResponseData( int id, int parent ) {
            this.id = id;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format( "{id: %d, parent: %d}", id, parent );
        }
    }
```

Also, this code expects that your tree is indeed a tree. Should there be any loops, it will cycle indefinitely, eventually failing with stack overflow.

Comment: This will group the data based on parent but i need to form list of list like I mentioned in the question .

Comment: then after fetching keys, iterate map, create list of lists, and start filtering them with key you have got. It will not take much code to do that will be much shorter, so that can be done

Comment: Thats where I am struggling to handle and I am not able to get the my expected output. Also my data will not come in order and my order will be different also

Comment: You can convert the map to a list of lists with `new ArrayList<>( map.values() )`

Comment: Also, what is the order you want to have the data in? You can use the `Stream#sorted` method to sort the data.

Comment: I am getting the same output which I am getting earlier in my code but I need a different output. Please check the my expected output @OndraK. .

Comment: I see you're grouping elements with parent 2, 3 and 4 together. How? What's the rule? You can write your own logic in the `Collectors#groupingBy` method by passing it the lambda you want.

Comment: I need to maintain the list based on levels . current level list are children to previous levels. And we can able to find by parent. first level -1 by default and next levels are based parent. So first level contain the object id 1 and next level will be what are all the object contains parent 1 and similarly . third level objects parent are present in level2 @OndraK.

Comment: Okay, that was not evident from your question - in that case you need to use as the grouping lambda an actual function that finds out the level of a node. As your tree is not a binary tree, it would be good to build an actual tree structure and recursively traverse parents it to find out the level of a node.

Comment: We cant use tree structure because level one contains more data and note single node @OndraK.

Comment: That just means that you have multiple trees - try representing each of them in a tree structure and traverse recursively to parent as described, the levels of all individual trees are equivalent.

Comment: @Abdul the best possible solution is using streams. So above answer is the correct one. If you are interested to how these grouping is done in NodeJS please check following package https://www.npmjs.com/package/group-array

Comment: @AlexpandiyanChokkan Above answer provides the grouping of my data based on the parent but further, I need to create a level of a list based on the parent-child relationship. I accept now we need to use streams. Please check my expected output for reference. I will check the group-array and update if any

Comment: @Abdul I have updated my answer with a simple implementation of the tree structure with the `getLevel` method.

Comment: @OndraK. Thanks for the answer . How this will work If i change my id and parent id to string. For Integer it works fine. When I convert the same with string not working

Comment: In that case go for a map instead of arraylist, the rest of the logic remains exactly the same.

Comment: @OndraK. I will change it to map and check.

Comment: @OndraK. If I change to map not working for me. Can you please refactor your answer

Comment: I think this post answers your _original_ question well, though (you did not mention strings in your question). If you wish, I will be happy to help you with map implementation, let's move the discussion to chat though, as this comment exchange is getting quite long and as you've confirmed, it solves the problem in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196927/discussion-between-abdul-and-ondra-k).

Comment: If my answer helped you, perhaps you also want to award the bounty? :)

Comment: I am trying to add bounty for you but the error is thrown states that I may award bounty after 6 hours. I will provide you the bounty after 6 hours. @OndraK.